# Compiling a C++ application on Windows 7, but execute it on Win2003 Server

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, windows-server-2003, manifest

I have a C++ application (quite complex, multiple projects) in Visual Studio 2008, that produces a single dll. Recently I switched to Windows 7, but had previously been compiling under Windows XP. Suddenly the dll in question cannot be loaded by another application, i.e. on a machine running Windows 2003 Server.

I've been trying various things:

- I've installed the VC9.0 redistributable package on the server
- Also copied various .dll's from that package to the application folder
- The project is of course compiled in release  mode

When I run depends.exe on the client machine, I do get the following error:

"Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "my_dll.dll" contains errors. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem (14001).
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."

and the icon for shlwapi.dll has a red overlay icon.

This didn't happen when I was compiling under WinXP, so I'm guessing that there really is no problem with the .dll's on the client machine, but somewhere there is a reference to that particular version of some dll.

Does anyone know what would be the best way to resolve this?

Regards,
Daníel

Comment: Is your Windows 7 box 64-bit?

Comment: Have you checked if msdn has some information about this error? This is the first thing you should have tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information in "BLAH.EXE" contains errors.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254076/error-the-side-by-side-configuration-information-in-blah-exe-contains-errors)

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/22266-Side-by-side-screwup/

Comment: An error in shlwapi.dll doesn't matter if it's indirectly included via another Microsoft DLL.

Comment: Andy: no, its just a regular 32-bit version.
SigTerm: yes, and I've googled a lot. The problem is to use the correct keywords, and I haven't managed to find the correct ones yet.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found it, and it turns out to be the same problem as described here:

[vcredist_x86.dll and version 8.0.50727.4053](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582844/vcredist-x86-dll-and-version-8-0-50727-4053)

I had to compare the resources of the old binary with the new one, to notice the difference.