# DLL Dependency Check Software

Tags: dll, dependencies

i have .exe application that need to runs on another computer but the application failed to initialized 0xc0150002.

Therefore, i try to install VC++ Redistribute Package but still cannot solve it.

Any software that can checks what dll missing on the particular computer ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for DLL dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use depends.exe (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) , it may fulfill your needs

Comment: I have checks it using the above mentioned software but shows this error

Comment: Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\documents and settings\user\desktop\debug\QTCORE4.DLL" contains errors. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem (14001).

Comment: Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\documents and settings\user\desktop\debug\QTGUI4.DLL" contains errors. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem (14001).
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
The Qt library is located at same directory with the exe. Please help.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254076/error-the-side-by-side-configuration-information-in-blah-exe-contains-errors but could not understand.