# Dependency Walker Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "ABC.DLL" contains errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dependencies, msvcrt, side-by-side

I am running a program that I built in Visual Studio 2010 which uses a third party DLL "ABC.DLL". I am on Windows 7 64-bits.

However, it fails to run due to one DLL. When running Dependency walker on this DLL, i get the following error:

> Error: The Side-by-Side configuration
>   information for "...\ABC.DLL" contains
>   errors. The application has failed to
>   start because its side-by-side
>   configuration is incorrect. Please see
>   the application event log or use the
>   command-line sxstrace.exe tool for
>   more detail (14001).

with missing dependencies MSCVR80.DLL and MSVCP80.DLL.

I have tried all the solutions in this following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254076/error-the-side-by-side-configuration-information-in-blah-exe-contains-errors) but I still am getting the same error.

The ABC.DLL is a third party library that was built in Visual Studio 2005, and I have no way to rebuild it.

I have installed Visual Studio C++ 2005 Redistributable, and tried copying the DLL's taken from another computer (since I do not have them in my computer) and nothing works.

Comment: Do the program run? Or is the error just in Dependancy walker?

Comment: +1 for running Dependency Walker...

Comment: The program does not run, that is why I used the Dependency walker. I will edit my post.

Comment: OK, deleted my answer, thought it was a problem only with dependency walker

Comment: Installing the redist should have solved the problem.  Be sure that you got the right version, there are 3 of them.  Using different versions of the CRT is *very* unhealthy, hard to diagnose memory leaks are common since the heap isn't shared.  You can't have a function that returns std::string for example.  A valid license to use the DLL should always include a way to get updates.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the manifest in the DLL to determine which version of the Visual C++ runtime you need to install.  There are several of them out there; and chances are, you are just using the wrong one.

There are five installers I have found so far.

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 RTM (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3387) (Version 8.0.50727.42)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5638) (Version 8.0.50727.762)
- [KB961894 – VC++ Post 2005 SP1](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB961894/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2067) (Version 8.0.50727.3079)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 ATL Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14431) (Version 8.0.50727.4053)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 MFC Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26347) (Version 8.0.50727.6195)

If the manifest specifies a version that isn't in the list above, you need to contact the makers of the DLL in question.  They should be able to provide you with an installer.